# Animate a chess line

Tags: animations, chess, chessboard

I would like to animate a line of a chess opening but the only way I found is kinda difficult or repetitive so I would like to write a command that allows me to do so.

Here is an example:

```
\newchessgame

\begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{1}%

\chessboard
\newframe\hidemoves{1.e4}%

\chessboard
\newframe\hidemoves{1... e5}%

\chessboard
\newframe\hidemoves{2. Nc3}%

\chessboard
\newframe\hidemoves{2... Nf6}%

\chessboard
\newframe\hidemoves{3.f4}%

\chessboard
\newframe\hidemoves{3... exf4}%

\chessboard
\end{animateinline}
```

And my idea is :

```
\newcommand{\ChessAnimate}[1]
{
    \begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{1}%
        \foreach \n in {#1}
        {
        \chessboard
        \newframe
        \mainline{\n}%
        }
    \chessboard
    \end{animateinline}
}
```

Hower it does not compile.
In addition I would like to link the move (that now I'm hiding) to the position of the chessboard.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Here is the code I used and that does not compile.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Accenti

\usepackage{xskak, chessboard, animate}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry} %Gestione delle dimensioni del foglio
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\geometry{
     a4paper,
     total={170mm,250mm},% Spessore e altezza del corpo 
                        %total={larghezza, altezza}
     top=20mm,
 }

\newcommand{\ChessAnimate}[1]
    {
        \begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{1}%
            \foreach \n in {#1}
            {
            \chessboard
            \newframe
            \mainline{\n}%
            }
        \chessboard
        \end{animateinline}
    }
    
\title{Title} 
\author{Name}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \ChessAnimate{1.e4 e5 2.Nc3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting code fragments, it's helpful to turn the fragments into a complete compilable document that people can play with. Then it's clear what packages you are using and what you've actually done.

Comment: the xskak documentation has on page 37 an example which loops through a game.

Comment: Of course, here it is the complete code, I will update the post

Comment: Sorry, where is the documentation? I'm kinda new to LaTeX

Comment: @Matteo [https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xskak](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xskak).
You can also run `texdoc xskak` from a command line

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, do you have any suggestions about how to link a frame to a move that the command \mainline{moves} displays?